# How to put a DLL in the Bin folder of a web application published in Windows Azure without referencing it?

Tags: .net, azure

This question seems weird but weird problems often require weird solutions.

I'm having a problem with Windows Azure and SignalR. [As I described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987720/signalr-on-azure-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-enterpriseservices-wra), the assembly `System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll` is not being found and my application is crashing from time to time.

I cannot explicitely add a reference to `System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll`. Visual Studio won't let me. There's something different with this DLL. But, when I put this DLL in the web application bin folder, I won't have any problems :). Everything works fine.

So I had an idea.. I'd put `System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll` inside my web application as a resource and set `Copy to Output Directory` as true. This way, I'd have a DLL in the bin folder without having a reference to it.

This situation I described works perfecly in the emulator but I just can't publish my application to Azure anymore.

```
Error   30  The "ProvideAssemblyProcessorArchitecture" task failed unexpectedly.
System.BadImageFormatException: The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)
```

It seems that Azure will pre-process the assemblies prior to publishing. During this processes it will throw an error.

Is there any way I can put this assembly in the bin folder of my web application?

Comment: Any dll that has its "Copy to output directory" property set to "Copy Always" will be copied to the bin folder, so that alone should be enough. This is what you'd normally do with native dll's, but yours is an assembly so you should add a reference instead. It sounds like the source of the problem is the dll itself rather than Azure.

Comment: @ShahinDohan. Thanks for the response. Yes. There's something unusual with this DLL that won't allow me to add a refernce to it. Neither it will pass the Azure publisher validator.

Comment: Not a good solution but you could always use a startup task to copy it into the bin folder (zip it up if you must hide it from Azure process validation stuff).

Comment: @Jaxidian. This is exactly what I ended up doing. =/ Thanks.